# Python initialise Struct

Tags: python, structure, ctypes

I have a block of memory with binary data. 
The block was created with `ctypes.create_string_buffer`, so the data is mutable, and accessible as an array.

Each 32 bits are made up of a pair, a 20 bit unsigned integer, and a 12 bit unsigned integer.

I want to access the nth element pair, and change the values in the memory block.

I have a structure:

```
from ctypes import *
class Int(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("first",  c_uint, 20),
                ("second",  c_uint, 12)]
```

How do I populate the Structure from my data?
Is there a C like pointer I can set to point the structure at my data?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array type of your `Int` by multiplying your structure type by its length; here I'm using `5` as an example, you can use whatever length you need:

```
IntArray5 = Int * 5
arr = IntArray5()
```

If you need to use different lengths each time, there's no need to name the type, you can just use:

```
arr = (Int * 5)()
```

Then rather than passing your string buffer to the C function, reading into that, and needing to do a conversion, it's probably best if you just pass your array into the function that will populate it:

```
myfunc = libfoo.myfunc
myfunc(arr, len(arr))
```

Now you should be able to access the elements of `arr`:

```
print arr[0].first
print arr[0].second
```

However, if for some reason you can't pass that array in to the function directly, and instead need to take an existing string buffer and produce an array of `Int` that shares the buffer, you can use `from_buffer` as eryksun suggests:

```
arr = (Int * 5).from_buffer(buff)
```

Or if you wanted to copy into a new array rather than sharing the underlying buffer:

```
arr = (Int * 5).from_buffer_copy(buff)
```

Comment: @eryksun Yes, you're right, that part was unclear. I've tried to clarify a little in an edit.

Comment: The two concepts I was missing were (Int * 5) and from_buffer. It works, Thanks.